# Wordpress ACF how to display something other than post title for custom relationship field in Admin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom post types for which having a 'title' field doesn't really make sense, so the post type has none.

Problem is that when you use a post type in a relationship, the user interface for picking which posts to relate wants to display the title.

In the box where you are choosing posts (clicking them and they move to the right pane), can a field other that 'title' be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It's doable. I would use a filter hook provided by acf plugin `'acf/fields/relationship/result/name=related_posts'`. Take a look at the following code:

```php
add_filter( 'acf/fields/relationship/result/name=related_posts', 'my_custom_title', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_title( $title, $acf_array ) {

    // You could remove the $title altogether or you could add something meaningful to it such as time stamp or anything that would make sense!
    return $title . "Adding somthing meaningful to the title!";

}
```